# is there a detailed documentation for libpd Python API?

Tags: python, puredata, libpd

I'm working with [libpd](https://github.com/libpd) for Python, and I can't seem to find a detailed API.  I would at least like a simple list of methods available.

The best I can find is here: https://github.com/libpd/libpd/wiki/Python-API
Which has a heading for "Detailed API Documentation", but under that, it just says:  "Anyone care to elaborate or link here?"

If it does not exist, I would like to document it as I go, but if it already exists somewhere, that (and so much figuring out) would be a bit of a waste of time.

Thank you!!

Comment: You might want to ask on their mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I found was you can use the C API documentation, BUT there are more methods and a PdManager class added to the Python version which were not documented (which were the things I wanted to know about)

So I documented those extra things here:

http://mikesperone.com/files/libpdPythonAPIdoc.pdf

it's not super detailed and many things are just references to the methods in the C API, but hopefully it will help others who are also looking

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you are really asking for a `detailed documentation for the API`  rather than a `detailed API`:

the python-API of libpd is just a thin wrapper around the C-API.

Since the C-API is [documented in the wiki](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/wiki/libpd) you better just use that one.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the documentation for the API, thank you.  The C API is great and very helpful, but there are other methods in the Python examples that are not documented there that make me believe there may be Python-specific classes, methods, etc... For example `m = PdManager(1, 2, 44100, 1)` and `m.process()`